# Prestashop - rearranging elements in hook_top for custom template

Tags: php, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I'm new to Prestashop, altough i've already read lots of documentation. Anyways i'm making a custom theme for Prestashop, and i have trouble with moving default modules that are assigned in {HOOK}'s. For example I'd like to move search bar from TOP to Navigation. Other example could be moving logged user info module to bar above page header.

I know i could remove module in admin for specific page element, but because this is CUSTOM THEME it would force user to make changes in admin modules. I want to make the changes straight in my theme folder. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do it.

1) The best way to do it, is to use css position (absolute, relative etc etc) and then using **left, right, top and bottom or mornings (left, right, top and bottom)**. This way , the core modules will still remain the same as these are. Mostly only css changes will occur.

2) You can do it by making changes in the module and assign them to other hooks according to your needs. For some places, you may not have hooks, for which you will need to create your own hooks and then make changes in the module(s) to be placed on that hook.

Way 2 is not good and is complex. Way 1 is clean, easy and only requires changes in css and may be in modules template files.

If you are also making changes in modules template files, then move those template files to your **themes/your_theme_name/modules/** folder. For example you are making changes in blockcart module template files, then move those template files to **your_theme/modules/blockcart/** folder. This is a best practice to avoid updates over ride your changed template files.

Comment: Thanks for answer, well using position absolute is kinda messy way to do things. I can't find clear information or even tutorials about the 2nd way you said.

Comment: using position may seems missy, but you will get to use it, when you practice. Try using relative position if absolute is not working for you. I use it all the time, and it works fine even in IE. For second option, try to search for creating a module in PS, and also creating a new hook in PS. Then using those both info, you may be able to do the second way. But still i recommend way 1, if you just practice it a little.